# How do I return a string from a DLL using Win32API in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, dll

At the moment I can only use the win32api in Ruby, so no ffi etc. In Ruby I'm loading a
DLL and passing a string, I am expecting the same string to be returned.
Here is the code:

### Ruby Code

```
string = "hello"
p = Win32API.new('C:/func/testFunc', 'Print', ['P'], 'S')
p.call(string)
```

### Output

```
=> 7476721
```

### DLL

```
extern (C)export char* Print(char* am)
{  
   return am;
}
```

I'm getting numbers instead of 'hello'. I'm guessing it's the address of the value I just passed to the dll. Could someone show me what the proper method is to retrieve a string from a DLL.

Comment: Good question -- I am having the same problem...  Did you have any luck on this one?

Answer (score 0):

This is *not* my forte in ruby, but I found the question interesting. Win32API takes and returns (generally) Pointers as datatypes. Which means you should be passing the variable pointer and the DLL will edit the pointer. Its up to you to pack and unpack these as appropriate (not helped by the fact that the Win32API specs are dreadful). Here's some good examples:

http://www.rubytips.org/2008/05/13/accessing-windows-api-from-ruby-using-win32api-library/

I don't think there's an return (export) type of 'S'. The only valid options are n,l,i & p. See this documentation here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/lib_windows.html